# Create slug out of existing table using foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a two tables - Campaigns and Products which are connected via foreign key (`product_id`)

*Campaigns*

`|id| |product_id| |slug|`

*Products*

`|id| |product_name|`

How can I generate slugs into `slug` column out of Products table.

For example product with `product_name = "Pro Evolution Soccer 2017"` has an `id = 1`. How can I generate the slug `Pro-evolution-soccer-2017-1` into Campaigns table? Probably I should use Laravel helper function `str_slug($title, $separator);`, but I don't know how...

Btw I have a more than 500 000 products which need to be generated as slugs...

Comment: Why you storing the `slug` in Campaigns table, not in Products table ?

Comment: If the last part is always the product id, why bother storing the slug? You can generate it on the fly and you can get the product from the slug.

Comment: @Jerodev That would be ideal. How can I generate it on the fly?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably save this in the Products table on create and update. If you do this one time, in a separate table, it's going to cause issues if/when the Products.product_name changes.

```
$product->slug = str_slug($product->product_name, '-');
```

To update the existing items, you could create a migration to add the `slug` field to Product, then select all products, iterate through them, and set the slug value as I did above.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use App\Models\Product;

class CreateFlightsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('Products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('slug');
        });

        foreach (Product::all() as $product) {
            $product->slug = str_slug($product->product_name, '-');
            $product->save();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('Products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('slug');
        });
    }
}
```

Then just `php artisan migrate` from the commandline.

Comment: I guess you're right. I should create slugs in Products table... But how can I do this without migrations?

Comment: You would want to add the new column with a migration, that's the proper place to do it for a number of reasons. Why wouldn't want to use a migration?

Comment: Ok, I've done it with migration, but slug column is empty. I think `Product::all()` won't fetch anything since I have more than 500 000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command to do this job [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands)

and run a loop to create and save all these slugs via command line.

Also this method could be used in the future or schedule it to run often and fill the new empty rows.